# UWP User Controls and Default Values

Tags: c#, uwp, components, controls

I am trying to create an UWP User Control for the first time. One very basic thing I want is automatic Width and Height at DESIGN-TIME and RUN-TIME based on the content of the user control. Simple enough in theory, but whenever I build the control and drop it on a form, it has this default "Width=100" value. Same thing with the Height.

Here is the simple XAML code i have so far:

```
    <UserControl
    x:Class="JTE.JTreeItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:JTE"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Width="Auto"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,32,0,0" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But when I drag the control from the toolbox to a page this is what I get:

```
<local:JTreeItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="247,305,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Both the Width and the Height are 100 by default. But why? How can I change this? This seems so simple, yet adding:

```
Width="Auto"
```

Does not solve this. Removing it does not solve it. Any value I put there gets ignored, for example, if I do this:

```
Width="199"
```

Nothing happens. I get the same 100 default value for the Width and the Height.

Why is this so not intuitive? There seems to be no syntax errors in the XAML, so what is happening there?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019.

If any of you can help, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance!!!

EDIT: Added a few things for clarity.

Comment: Do you mean when you drag the UserControl to the designer, you want to generate the right values of width and height based on its content? If you remove the Width and Height which are generated when you drag the UserControl to the designer, can the UserControl display well?

Comment: @CarlosNina: Stop dragging and start writing XAML?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT When I drag my User Control from the tool box into the Main Page or Form of my UWP test app at DESIGN TIME it automatically places these "default" values on it. If I removed them THERE it would work as you would expect. But doing it that way means that any user of my control would have to manually remove these default values by hand every time they put them on a page/form.. I want to set these values on the control itself, but for some reason this seems to be unnecessarily difficult, because I can't find a way to do it yet.

Comment: @mm8 I wrote XAML. The user control XAML code up there was written by me. I assume you misunderstood because the whole reason we write user controls is to not keep writing code again and again.

Comment: @CarlosNina: I thnink you misunderstood me. Why do you drag controls from the toolbox instead of writing XAML?

Comment: @mm8 Doesn't that partially defeat the purpose? You write the XAML ONCE on your User control, you set it all up, and then you don't write what you wrote ever again,and now you know have a visual object that you wrote and prepared ONCE not every time you drag it?